# Is there a smart algorithm of finding the maximum of $X^{\top}a$ with $X$ and $a$ both belong to some compact convex set?

Tags: optimization, convex, calculus

Suppose $X\in\mathcal{X}\subset R^k$ and $a\in\mathcal{A}\subset R^k$, where $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ are both compact convex set.

Is there a systematic way of finding the maximum of $X^{\top}a$ over $\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{A}$?

Intuitively I guess such maximum is only achieved on the boundary of $\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{A}$, but discretizing both sets and checking all boundary points would be computationally quite costly, so I want some smart algorithm that is computationally less intensive. You can add more restrictions to $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ as long as they are still compact and convex.

Comment: Your intuition is correct, but could you clarify what you mean by "systematic way"?

Comment: @whuber Thanks, Whuber! I guess I meant a smart and systematic way. As we can always discretize both sets and try all boundary points, but it will be computationally too costly when $k$ gets large.

Comment: Do you mean an *algorithm?* If so, you need to tell us what the inputs are. How exactly are these sets described? As intersections of half spaces? As epigraphs of arbitrary convex functions? As the hulls of arbitrary finite sets of vertices?  Something else?

Comment: @whuber Yes, I want an algorithm. In my problem the inputs are just general compact and convex sets $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ without further restrictions. But if there exists smart algorithm for any of the more restricted cases you mentioned, that would be great too.

Comment: It's not about additional restrictions on the convex sets, it's about how you're allowed to ask about information related to them. For instance, if you want a computer algorithm to find the optimum, how are the sets $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ described in the computer's memory? Obviously this can't be a list of points in the set (unless the sets are singletons), because convexity implies that the sets would contain a continuum of points, and a computer cannot store that information directly. Are you given a function $g(x)$, for instance, where $\mathcal{A}:=\{x:g(x) \le c\}$?

Comment: Or, possibly, instead of having this function $g$ you are representing the set $\mathcal{A}$ by a set of points that you know belong to the set, and considering the smallest convex set that contains them (the convex hull @whuber was describing). Or maybe you know the boundary of $\mathcal{A}$ is a piecewise linear curve that you know all of the breakpoints on?

Comment: @ericperkerson Thanks! I see your point, let me think further on how I can improve the statement of the problem.